# Machine Learning Error when loading mlmodel "No known class for loading model type > MLModelType_pipelineClassifier"

Tags: xcode, coreml, createml, mlmodel, xcode10beta3

I have created a mlmodel with Playground and imported into my Xcode project though when it runs I'm getting this error.

The error is also flagged here in the code of the mlmodel.
[image]

> ObjectClassifier[24610:8307770] [coreml] MLModelAsset:
>   modelWithError: load failed with error Error Domain=com.apple.CoreML
>   Code=3 "No known class for loading model type
>   MLModelType_pipelineClassifier" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No
>   known class for loading model type MLModelType_pipelineClassifier}

Why would the code that is automatically created when making the mlmodel in the playground be causing this error?

Comment: It has something to do with the type of model that is created by the playground as I can get my code to run no problem with a "Custom Vision" model. The "Custom Vision" model is of type : Neural Network Classifier and the playground model is of type : Image Classifier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me the problem is with IOS-11. I faced the same issue, then I tried with **IOS12** device and it works fine.

Comment: They really need to change the documentation as they say it's compatible with iOS11

Comment: I was trying to do some coin classification using CoreML, but it turns out to work no good.

Comment: @uplearnedu.com I'm using about 1800 images and I shifted to turicreate. Now it seems to work better.

Comment: I'd like this to work with iOS 11... it should do right?

Comment: @Magoo Yeah it should but I'm not sure if it really works now for iOS 11, I think you can try a demo.